# Strip away empty columns on the left side of a named range

Tags: excel, vba

Let's suppose that rangeData refers to a range of cells in a spreadsheet.

If the right most column is empty, I can strip it away by doing this:

```
rangeData = rangeData.CurrentRegion
```

But what if the left most column of rangeData is empty?

How do I strip away that column and have rangeData refer to only the columns with values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird: by the way `CurrentRegion` is described in the documentation, I would have expected it not to include empty rows on top or empty columns on the left.

You could go through the columns from the left looking for the first non-empty column, and then set the range based on that as follows:

```vb
    Dim i As Long
    Dim firstNonEmptyColumn As Long
    For i = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngData.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn) <> 0 Then
            firstNonEmptyColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Set rngData = Range(rngData.Cells(1, firstNonEmptyColumn), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, rngData.Columns.Count))
```

You could do something similar for empty rows on top.

---

### Update

Let me clarify my assumptions and provide more details: I'm assuming that the starting condition is `rngData` set to contiguous range that contains non-empty cells surrounded by some rows/columns that are empty. And that the goal is to change rngData so that there are no empty columns on the left.

**Also assumed:** there are no other non-empty cells above or below on the sheet outside the range of `rngData`. (See below for a different assumption.)

To initialize `rngData`, I'll start with a selection that contains the non-empty cells.

[image]

Then I'll run the following—at the end I make `rngData` the selection to easily visualize the change to `rngData`:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim firstNonEmptyColumn As Long
    
    Set rngData = Selection
    
    For i = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngData.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn) <> 0 Then
            firstNonEmptyColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Set rngData = Range(rngData.Cells(1, firstNonEmptyColumn), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, rngData.Columns.Count))
    rngData.Select
End Sub
```

Here's the resulting selection:

[image]

Note that `.CurrentRegion` will use the first (top left) cell as its starting reference point. If that cell is empty (as in my example here), then the current region for that will be only that cell. `.CurrentRegion` is really meant to be used in cases in which the first cell is non-empty.

But what I showed used `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` on all the cells in a column to determine if the column is (non)empty (It could also be used with `.EntireRow`.) So it isn't limited by the *first* cell in the range.

---

### Second update

In the previous update, it was assumed that there aren't non-empty cells above or below on the sheet outside the range of `rngData`. Because of that assumption, `.EntireColumn` was used to check for non-empty cells.

If that's not an appropriate assumption for the situation, then the test for columns with non-empty cells can be limited only to cells within the range of `rngData`. The following sub will initialize `rngData` as before, but check for non-empty columns limited only to the cells within `rngData`:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim dataColumn As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim firstNonEmptyColumn As Long
    
    Set rngData = Selection
    
    For i = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
        Set dataColumn = Range(rngData.Cells(1, i), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, i))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataColumn) <> 0 Then
            firstNonEmptyColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    Set rngData = Range(rngData.Cells(1, firstNonEmptyColumn), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, rngData.Columns.Count))
    rngData.Select
End Sub
```

Rather than using `.EntireColumn` before, `dataColumn` is set to a range of cells within `rngData` using `Range(rngData.Cells(1, i), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, i))`. That is, cells in the _i_th column for rows within `rngData` from 1 to the number of rows in `rngData`.

For a test, here's a starting selection:

[image]

Note the non-empty cells below the selection that gets used for `rngData`. After running that sub, here's the resulting selection:

[image]

Comment: The bit that is supposed to detect the first non empty column doesn't seem to work. could you check if there is a bug ?

Comment: It works for me. Though maybe we have different assumptions about what's expected. I'll update my answer with more details.

Comment: I found the bug. Your code chunk will work if the entire column of the tab is empty. But that is not what I meant. I meant that if only the cells inside of the named range of the first column is empty. The code should not be affected by values outside of the named range.

Comment: Ah, OK. Clarifying assumptions. I'll update the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It shows you how to remove the first or last column of a given range.

```
Private Sub Test()

    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Set Rng = Range("A1:D15")
    
    ' remove last column
    With Rng
        Set Rng = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1)
    End With
    Debug.Print Rng.Address
    
    
    Set Rng = Range("A1:D15")
    
    ' remove first column
    With Rng
        Set Rng = .Offset(0, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1)
    End With
    Debug.Print Rng.Address
End Sub
```

You could use the same methods to add columns, or to add/remove rows.